# Why hashes of all commits changed when I rebase with WSL git?

Tags: git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, git-rebase, wsl-2

I have a repository **cloned with Windows git**, when I tried to rebase the repository with **WSL git**, somethings weird happens.

Here are my input

```
pick 9f37600 Initial commit
pick 1942413 refactor: remove useless pages
pick ded8102 WIP 1
pick dde7c08 WIP 2
pick cc2334e WIP 3
pick 6567c27 WIP 4
pick 918a347 WIP 5
pick 0f4e802 WIP 6
pick ebacf31 WIP 7
pick 50d48e4 WIP 8
pick d36f95c WIP 9
pick b7e7065 WIP 10
pick a6bc8a6 WIP 11
fixup 7607be9 WIP 12
```

When I rebase with Windows git, commit from "Initial commit" to "WIP 10" keep untouched and only commit hash of "WIP 11" changed . However, WSL git changed hashes of all commit.

How can I avoid WSL git changing hashes of other commits?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What command are you running to do the rebase? The only change *should* be that WIP 11 and WIP 12 are folded into a new commit on top of the existing WIP 10.

Comment: The existence of "Initial commit" makes be wonder what you are rebasing on *to*.

Comment: I used the command `git rebase -i --root` and the result is different in Windows and WSL. Is it a config/line ending issue?

Comment: Ah, probably. I can't reproduce using `--root`, either, but I have no EOL issues.

Comment: Are you using WSL git? WIndows git worked as expected but not WSL git. I am just wondoring if I can get WSL git working too.

Comment: Preserve the branch before rebase and `diff` it with post-rebase result. What changed? If `git diff` doesn't show any difference try to compare `git log --format=fuller`.

Answer (score 0):

There might not be a fix for this question.

I ran `git cat-file commit <SHA>` on the "same" commit before and after rebase. I found that WSL git changes the committer timestamp on rebase so the hash is changed too. In contrast, Windows git uses the old committer timestamp so the hash remains changed after rebase operations.

Here's the cat-file of a commit before rebase.

```
tree 7d804c5a84c61fbdc26ed443a7b9900fcf536d0f
author my-name <my-name@example.com> 1578669828 +0800
committer my-name <my-name@example.com> 1582870913 +0800

Initial commit
```

Here's the cat-file after it is rebased by WSL git.

```
tree 7d804c5a84c61fbdc26ed443a7b9900fcf536d0f
author my-name <my-name@example.com> 1578669828 +0800
committer my-name <my-name@example.com> 1589713427 +0800

Initial commit
```